# Deploying Microsoft Intune

Tags: mdm

I'm here going to deploy (Intune) in our company however, the previous users use to Mass360 as the MDM. Is there any way we can detect when users will receive emails outside of Microsoft Intune? We are planning to block them until they enroll in Intune.

Thank you all in advance.

I've tried researching on this topic, nothing pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Getting emails outside of Intune is a vague thing. I think you are referring to receiving emails on a not managed device. If you want to block that, you would do it with a AAD conditional access policy, e.g. only allow all cloud resources on a joined / compliant device